# chromium checkout and build error gclient error

Tags: chromium

Somehow the fetch and gclient is not valid.

```
zelong@zelong-ThinkPad-T430:~/chromium/src$ gclient sync --verbose
CIPD selfupdate failed. Trying to bootstrap the CIPD client from scratch...
curl: (7) Failed to connect to chrome-infra-packages.appspot.com port 443: Connection timed out
^C
```

depot_tools is in the path:

```
zelong@zelong-ThinkPad-T430:~/chromium/src$ echo $PATH
/home/zelong/bin:/home/zelong/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/media/zelong/2828a0f1-cc41-4428-854d-a7a18c59f5c6/Code/depot_tools:/media/zelong/2828a0f1-cc41-4428-854d-a7a18c59f5c6/fuchsia_source/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin:/media/zelong/2828a0f1-cc41-4428-854d-a7a18c59f5c6/Opera/ofa/work/chromium/src/third_party/depot_tools/ninja
```

and fetch and gclient is in the path:

```
zelong@zelong-ThinkPad-T430:~/chromium/src$ ls -la /media/zelong/2828a0f1-cc41-4428-854d-a7a18c59f5c6/Code/depot_tools
total 19876
drwxrwxr-x 20 zelong zelong    12288 6月  27 16:54 .
drwxrwxr-x 23 zelong zelong     4096 11月  5  2019 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     5069 1月  22 14:09 auth.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1159 6月  27 15:28 autoninja
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1470 1月  22 14:09 autoninja.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     5829 6月  27 15:28 autoninja.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      320 10月 12  2019 bb
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      247 10月 12  2019 bb.bat
drwxrwxr-x  2 zelong zelong     4096 6月  27 15:28 bootstrap
drwxrwxr-x  6 zelong zelong     4096 1月  22 14:11 bootstrap-3.8.0.chromium.8_bin
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      982 6月  27 15:28 bootstrap_python3
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      485 10月 12  2019 breakpad.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 zelong zelong        4 1月  22 14:09 cbuildbot -> cros
lrwxrwxrwx  1 zelong zelong        4 1月  22 14:09 chrome_set_ver -> cros
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     6623 6月  27 15:28 cipd
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     1815 6月  27 15:28 cipd.bat
drwxrwxr-x  5 zelong zelong     4096 1月  22 14:10 .cipd_bin
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      288 10月 12  2019 cipd_bin_setup.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      611 10月 12  2019 cipd_bin_setup.sh
-rwx--x--x  1 zelong zelong 17131837 1月  22 14:10 .cipd_client
drwxrwxr-x  2 zelong zelong     4096 1月  22 14:10 .cipd_client_cache
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong       54 6月  27 15:28 cipd_client_version
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     1513 6月  27 15:28 cipd_client_version.digests
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     4010 6月  27 15:28 .cipd_impl.ps1
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     2359 6月  27 15:28 cipd_manifest.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    13043 6月  27 15:28 cipd_manifest.versions
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      275 10月 12  2019 cit
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      410 10月 12  2019 cit.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     5071 10月 12  2019 cit.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      280 10月 12  2019 clang-format
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      415 10月 12  2019 clang-format.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      293 10月 12  2019 clang_format_merge_driver
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      428 10月 12  2019 clang_format_merge_driver.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     2457 10月 12  2019 clang_format_merge_driver.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     2657 10月 12  2019 clang_format.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      265 10月 12  2019 codereview.settings
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      298 10月 12  2019 compile_single_file
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      394 10月 12  2019 compile_single_file.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     2732 10月 12  2019 compile_single_file.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      390 10月 12  2019 cpplint.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     2394 10月 12  2019 cpplint_chromium.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong   235287 6月  27 15:28 cpplint.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     2728 6月  27 15:28 cros
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      328 10月 12  2019 crosjobs
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      196 6月  27 15:28 CROS_OWNERS
lrwxrwxrwx  1 zelong zelong        4 1月  22 14:09 cros_sdk -> cros
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1691 1月  22 14:09 detect_host_arch.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      300 10月 12  2019 download_from_google_storage
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      435 10月 12  2019 download_from_google_storage.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    24189 6月  27 15:28 download_from_google_storage.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1666 10月 12  2019 ensure_bootstrap
drwxrwxr-x  3 zelong zelong     4096 10月 12  2019 external_bin
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      768 6月  27 15:28 fetch
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      908 6月  27 15:28 fetch.bat
drwxrwxr-x  2 zelong zelong     4096 1月  22 14:09 fetch_configs
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    10340 6月  27 15:28 fetch.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    12462 6月  27 15:28 fix_encoding.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1122 6月  27 15:28 gclient
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1016 6月  27 15:28 gclient.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     2322 10月 12  2019 gclient_completion.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    31221 6月  27 15:28 gclient_eval.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     4179 10月 12  2019 gclient-new-workdir.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     5125 1月  22 14:09 gclient_paths.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong   119569 6月  27 15:28 gclient.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    62487 6月  27 15:28 gclient_scm.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    40645 6月  27 15:28 gclient_utils.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     4865 6月  27 15:28 gerrit_client.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    34346 6月  27 15:28 gerrit_util.py
drwxrwxr-x  8 zelong zelong     4096 6月  27 16:31 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     1528 10月 12  2019 .gitattributes
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-cache
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    28820 6月  27 15:28 git_cache.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      219 6月  27 15:28 git-cl
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1313 6月  27 15:28 git_cl_completion.sh
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong   192003 6月  27 15:28 git_cl.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    31344 6月  27 15:28 git_common.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    40415 10月 12  2019 git_common.pyc
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1730 10月 12  2019 git-crrev-parse
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     1800 10月 12  2019 git_dates.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-drover
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    15763 6月  27 15:28 git_drover.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-find-releases
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1976 6月  27 15:28 git_find_releases.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-footers
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     8567 6月  27 15:28 git_footers.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      256 6月  27 15:28 git-freeze
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      871 10月 12  2019 git_freezer.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      529 10月 12  2019 git-gs
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-hyper-blame
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    12524 6月  27 15:28 git_hyper_blame.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     1715 1月  22 14:09 .gitignore
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-map
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-map-branches
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    11294 6月  27 15:28 git_map_branches.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     4692 1月  22 14:09 git_map.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-mark-merge-base
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     2059 10月 12  2019 git_mark_merge_base.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-nav-downstream
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1971 6月  27 15:28 git_nav_downstream.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      236 10月 12  2019 git-nav-upstream
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-new-branch
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     3071 6月  27 15:28 git_new_branch.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-number
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     9637 6月  27 15:28 git_number.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-rebase-update
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    12239 6月  27 15:28 git_rebase_update.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-rename-branch
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1662 1月  22 14:09 git_rename_branch.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-reparent-branch
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     3229 10月 12  2019 git_reparent_branch.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      253 6月  27 15:28 git-retry
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     5795 10月 12  2019 git_retry.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      610 10月 12  2019 git-runhooks
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      215 6月  27 15:28 git-squash-branch
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      748 10月 12  2019 git_squash_branch.py
drwxrwxr-x  4 zelong zelong     4096 10月 12  2019 git-templates
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      504 6月  27 15:28 git-thaw
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      306 6月  27 15:28 git-upstream-diff
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     2044 10月 12  2019 git_upstream_diff.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      270 10月 12  2019 gn
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      405 10月 12  2019 gn.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     2991 10月 12  2019 gn.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      363 1月  22 14:09 goma_auth
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      277 6月  27 15:28 goma_auth.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      363 1月  22 14:09 goma_ctl
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      277 6月  27 15:28 goma_ctl.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      173 6月  27 15:28 GOMA_OWNERS
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     5636 1月  22 14:09 gsutil.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      731 6月  27 15:28 gsutil.py.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     2499 1月  22 14:09 gsutil.vpython
drwxrwxr-x  3 zelong zelong     4096 10月 12  2019 infra
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      321 10月 12  2019 led
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      255 10月 12  2019 led.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     1563 10月 12  2019 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     3010 6月  27 15:28 lockfile.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      328 10月 12  2019 luci-auth
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      255 10月 12  2019 luci-auth.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      325 10月 12  2019 lucicfg
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      259 10月 12  2019 lucicfg.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      102 6月  27 15:28 LUCI_OWNERS
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      331 10月 12  2019 mac_toolchain
drwxrwxr-x  6 zelong zelong     4096 10月 12  2019 man
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong       68 10月 12  2019 metrics.cfg
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     9425 6月  27 15:28 metrics.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     4526 1月  22 14:09 metrics.README.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     8811 10月 12  2019 metrics_utils.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    33598 6月  27 15:28 my_activity.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1279 1月  22 14:09 ninja
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong   504320 10月 12  2019 ninja.exe
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong   161640 10月 12  2019 ninja-linux32
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong   183344 10月 12  2019 ninja-linux64
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     1928 10月 12  2019 ninjalog.README.md
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     6620 6月  27 15:28 ninjalog_uploader.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     7201 10月 12  2019 ninjalog_uploader.pyc
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     3267 6月  27 15:28 ninjalog_uploader_wrapper.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong   184804 10月 12  2019 ninja-mac
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      951 6月  27 15:28 OWNERS
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    12798 6月  27 15:28 owners_finder.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    23510 6月  27 15:28 owners.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    14820 6月  27 15:28 post_build_ninja_summary.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    60823 6月  27 15:28 presubmit_canned_checks.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     5146 6月  27 15:28 PRESUBMIT.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    66572 6月  27 15:28 presubmit_support.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      282 10月 12  2019 profile.xml
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      323 10月 12  2019 prpc
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      250 10月 12  2019 prpc.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      302 10月 12  2019 pylint
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1894 1月  22 14:09 pylint-1.5
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1861 1月  22 14:09 pylint-1.6
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1861 1月  22 14:09 pylint-1.7
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1894 1月  22 14:09 pylint-1.8
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1894 1月  22 14:09 pylint-1.9
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      411 10月 12  2019 pylint.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1276 10月 12  2019 pylint_main.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     9351 6月  27 15:28 pylintrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 zelong zelong       42 1月  22 14:11 python3_bin_reldir.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 zelong zelong     4096 1月  22 14:09 python-bin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 zelong zelong       41 1月  22 14:11 python_bin_reldir.txt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     2154 6月  27 15:28 python_runner.sh
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      321 6月  27 15:28 rdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      248 6月  27 15:28 rdb.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     3579 10月 12  2019 README.gclient.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     4241 10月 12  2019 README.git-cl.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     2867 6月  27 15:28 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  4 zelong zelong     4096 6月  27 15:28 recipes
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    39141 6月  27 15:28 repo
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      783 6月  27 15:28 roll-dep
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      700 6月  27 15:28 roll-dep.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    10246 6月  27 15:28 roll_dep.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong    14148 6月  27 15:28 scm.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     4604 10月 12  2019 setup_color.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     3422 10月 12  2019 setup_color.pyc
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     9357 6月  27 15:28 split_cl.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong       65 1月  22 14:09 .style.yapf
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     8998 6月  27 15:28 subcommand.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     8020 6月  27 15:28 subprocess2.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     8487 10月 12  2019 subprocess2.pyc
drwxrwxr-x  2 zelong zelong     4096 6月  27 15:28 testing_support
drwxrwxr-x  3 zelong zelong     4096 6月  27 15:28 tests
drwxrwxr-x  9 zelong zelong     4096 1月  22 14:09 third_party
-rw-------  1 zelong zelong        0 6月  27 16:54 tmp.4pSSSQ0EwS
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     3865 6月  27 15:28 update_depot_tools
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     2055 6月  27 15:28 update_depot_tools.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     1112 10月 12  2019 update_depot_tools_toggle.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      604 10月 12  2019 upload_metrics.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong    10789 1月  22 14:09 upload_to_google_storage.py
drwxrwxr-x  2 zelong zelong     4096 1月  22 14:10 .versions
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1000 1月  22 14:09 vpython
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     1187 1月  22 14:09 .vpython
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1577 6月  27 15:28 vpython3
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      438 1月  22 14:09 .vpython3
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      603 6月  27 15:28 vpython3.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong      299 1月  22 14:09 vpython.bat
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      534 6月  27 15:28 WATCHLISTS
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     4411 1月  22 14:09 watchlists.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     1621 10月 12  2019 weekly
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong     2231 6月  27 15:28 win32imports.py
drwxrwxr-x  2 zelong zelong     4096 6月  27 15:28 win_toolchain
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong     2151 10月 12  2019 wtf
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      366 6月  27 15:28 yapf
-rwxrwxr-x  1 zelong zelong      409 10月 12  2019 yapf.bat
drwxrwxr-x  2 zelong zelong     4096 10月 12  2019 zsh-goodies
```

It may be related to cipd

```
zelong@zelong-ThinkPad-T430:~/chromium$ ls -la
total 92
drwxrwxr-x  4 zelong zelong  4096 6月  27 15:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 39 zelong zelong  4096 6月  27 16:02 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 zelong zelong  4096 3月  11 15:03 .cipd
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong   201 1月  22 14:11 .gclient
-rw-rw-r--  1 zelong zelong 72997 1月  22 18:32 .gclient_entries
drwxrwxr-x 57 zelong zelong  4096 6月  27 15:21 src
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try run step by step
https://github.com/anticrisis/docker-chromium-builder/blob/master/Dockerfile
may by your firewall blocked some http requests